# Bootstrap carousel multiple images responsive on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a bootstrap carousel that shows two images side by side on 'small' screen sizes and up, and only shows one image on 'x-small' devices.

I have used and modified [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/117282) to get the two images side by side, and I am using `$(window).width()` to detect the window size. It works fine when you load the page at a set width, but I can't get it to work on window resize. I have tried putting in

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   width = $(window).width();
});
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$('.carousel .item').each(function () {
  width = $(window).width();
  if (width > 768) {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

My site is [here](http://zac.thedesignoffice.co.uk/tbs)

EDIT: [here's a bootply](http://www.bootply.com/oeqCbXQKxW). The problem is when resizing from small to big only one image is displayed, and when resizing from big to small the images go underneath each other. It works correctly on page load at all sizes though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make this work. I have created two functions, one which appends the next image to each item in the carousel and one which removes those cloned images.

```
run = false;
var multiple = function() {
  $('.carousel .item').each(function () {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
         next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    run = true;
  });
};
var undo = function() {
  $('.carousel .item').each(function () {
    $(this).children().last().remove();
    run = false;
  });
};
```

If the window is greater than 768px on load I call the multiple images function right away

```
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
  multiple();
};
```

On window resize I only call the multiple function if it hasn't already been run and the window is 768px or greater. I call the undo function if the multiple function has already been called and the window width is less than 768px.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if (run==false && $(window).width() > 768) {
    multiple();
  } else if (run == true && $(window).width() < 768) {
    undo();
  }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/Lqwkm6Q2Qr)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use Bootstrap carousel take a look at [Slick- the last carousel you'll ever](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). You can define breakpoints for custom windows sizes pretty easy:

```
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```