# Bootstrap Carousel multiple image in single item when resize(Using jquery) without for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel, when i resizing the page based on carousel-inner width I need to make multiple images within the single item(without for loop). carousel-inner width was dynamically generated when i resizing the page.

[image: actual]

Actual Code :

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">


    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img_flower1.jpg" alt="Chania">page 1
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower">page 2
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_flower3.jpg" alt="Flower">page 3 
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="img_flower4.jpg" alt="Flower">page 4 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Expected Code :

[image]

```
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img_flower1.jpg" alt="Chania">page 1
       <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower">page 2
    </div>

    <div class="item">
     <img src="img_flower3.jpg" alt="Flower">page 3 
      <img src="img_flower4.jpg" alt="Flower">page 4 
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: use ($(window).width() > 768)  or try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662127/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-images-responsive-on-window-resize

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add responsiveness to your carousel items like this.

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <a href="#">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=demo" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

So that it gets adjusted as per new layout changes, small or medium screens.

Another option is to use another library for carousel. I would suggest have a look at [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). It has all the things you need.

For your scenario setting it is as simple as this.

```
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
```

If you want to use bootstrap carousel. Here is some sample code to test. Try opening in a full size window and then resize screen size.

```js
$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  
  for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
     next = $(this).siblings(':first');
   }
    
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

```css
.carousel-control     { width:  4%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:15px;background-image:none;}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -100%; }
 .carousel-inner .next        { left:  100%; }
 .carousel-inner .prev   { left: -100%; }
 .active > div { display:none; }
 .active > div:first-child { display:block; }

}
@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 992px ) {
 .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -50%; }
 .carousel-inner .next        { left:  50%; }
 .carousel-inner .prev   { left: -50%; }
 .active > div { display:none; }
 .active > div:first-child { display:block; }
 .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
}
@media (min-width: 992px ) {
 .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -16.7%; }
 .carousel-inner .next        { left:  16.7%; }
 .carousel-inner .prev   { left: -16.7%; } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h3>Testing Carousel</h3></div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
```